# how to "filter" Akka INFO logging output to different files?

Tags: scala, logging, akka

I am logging INFO on "orders" and INFO on "transactions" generated by a trading application that I am developing using Scala/Akka. Currently all of the output is going into a single log file, but I would like the information to go to separate files.

I have specified my `application.conf` as follows...

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "INFO"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}
```

...and here is my `logback.xml` file...

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="TRANSACTIONS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>log/transactions.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd} %X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="TRANSACTIONS" />
    </root>

    <appender name="ORDERS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>log/orders.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd} %X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ORDERS" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I have tried modifying my `logback.xml` file to include filters as follows

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="TRANSACTIONS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <filter class="domain.trading.DoubleAuctionMarket"/>
        <file>log/transactions.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd} %X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="TRANSACTIONS" />
    </root>

    <appender name="ORDERS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <filter class="domain.trading.Exchange"/>
        <file>log/orders.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd} %X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ORDERS" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

However, this generates runtime errors...

```
14:11:38,361 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Could not create component [filter] of type [domain.trading.DoubleAuctionMarket] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: domain.trading.DoubleAuctionMarket
at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: domain.trading.DoubleAuctionMarket
```

and

```
14:11:38,417 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Could not create component [filter] of type [domain.trading.Exchange] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: domain.trading.Exchange
at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: domain.trading.Exchange
```

Thoughts?

**[EDIT: Solution]** For completeness, I created two filters `TransactionsFilter` and `OrdersFilter` per the link provided in the answer below and stuck them in the `src/main/java/` directory of my project. Example filter looks like...

```
package filters;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.FilterReply;

public class OrdersFilter extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(ILoggingEvent event) {
        boolean isAskOrder = event.getFormattedMessage().contains("AskOrder");
        boolean isBidOrder = event.getFormattedMessage().contains("BidOrder");
        if ( isAskOrder || isBidOrder) {
            return FilterReply.ACCEPT;
        } else {
            return FilterReply.DENY;
        }
    }
}
```

I then edited my `logback.xml` file to to reference the newly created filters...

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="TRANSACTIONS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <filter class="filters/TransactionFilter"/>
        <file>log/transactions.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd} %X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="TRANSACTIONS" />
    </root>

    <appender name="ORDERS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <filter class="filters/OrderFilter"/>
        <file>log/orders.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd} %X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ORDERS" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did this work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you specify in the filter tag is not the type of files you want to accept, but the class-path of a filter class (possibly a custom one) you want to use to filter your logs.

So I guess you get that error as your classes do not implement a filter.

You should build your filter class as readable [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html), one per filter, and then reference those.